# How to cut my list to pieces (columns)?

Tags: r, list

I have a big data.frame `"MyList"` that looks something like this:

```
Year = c(2012, 2011, 2010) 
Object_1 = c(5.3, 10.1, 7.5) 
Object_2 = c(6.2, 4.6, 9.8) 
MyList = data.frame(Year, Object_1, Object_2)
```

I want to export .txt files, with the columns:

> Year, Object_1 => 1st .txt file
>
> Year, Object_2 => 2nd .txt file

( also, how can i specify the columns (`numeric`, `factor`, `logical`)  )

Any suggestions on how that might work?

edit: write.table is pointing in the right direction, but let me specify a bit....

I have about 300 columns (Objects) and i want to tell R: Always take column "Year" and one object-column and generate a .txt file (with separator = tab) from those two columns. Then take "Year" again and move on to the next object-column and generate the next .txt file. Name the files after their object column.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the `write.table` help. Use `?write.table`

Comment: In your first file you have to write `MyList[, c("Year", "Object_1")]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var in names(MyList)[names(MyList) != "Year"]){
  write.table(MyList[,c("Year", var)], file=paste0(var,".txt"),
              sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate your answer a bit?

Comment: here is my complete code:

    MyList <- read.csv("D:/Data/Data.csv",
    header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ".")



    for(var in names(MyList)[names(MyList) != "Year"]){
    write.table(MyList[,c("Year", var)], file=paste0(var,".txt"),
              sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)
}

If I run this it gives me this message:

Error in `[.data.frame`(MyList, , c("Year", var)) : 
  undefined columns selected

Any Ideas?